# Querying data from mysql wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new in WordPress I want to get all records from wp_posts table which are drafted, but no record found. My query is the follow:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;

    $resultsOb = $wpdb->get_results(
                        "SELECT ID,post_title 
                         FROM $wpdb->wp_posts 
                         WHERE post_status = 'draft'
                         "
                    );

    // loop the objects
    foreach($resultsOb AS $result) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $result->ID;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result->post_title;?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in function for this called [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). In your case, usage would look something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
);
$resultsOb = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: But I got the first record from table